# Version Control of Website Project (ASP.NET) with HgSccPackage_1.3.3

Tags: version-control, mercurial, asp.net-3.5

If my ASP.NET website (New->Website) resides in both of the following disparate directories, how do I keep them under version control?

%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Websites\Website4\ 
%USERPROFILE%\My Docuemnts\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Website4\

Is there a way to place these all in the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use web sites but web projects if it's an issue for you